# How to parameterize jenkins DSL job with pipeline script & docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I've created a DSL job **nv_dsl.groovy** as below,

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def fileContents = readFileFromWorkspace "nv_pipeline.groovy" 
def fileContents1 = readFileFromWorkspace "docker-compose.yaml"
def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()

template = engine.createTemplate(fileContents).make(binding.getVariables()).toString()

template1 = engine.createTemplate(fileContents1).make(binding.getVariables()).toString()


pipelineJob("${DSL_JOB}") {

  definition {
    cps { 
        script(template)
    }
  }
}
```

**nv_pipeline.groovy** as follows,

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {
    REPO = repository
  }

  parameters {
    choice name: "ENVIRONMENT", choices: environments
  }

  stages {
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
          echo "Deploying ${env.REPO} to ${params.ENVIRONMENT}..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: "3.3"
services:
${SERVICES}:
    restart: always
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    build:
      context: ${CONTEXT}
      args:
        NODE: ${NODE_ENV}
    ports:
        - ${PORTS}
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
    volumes:
      - ${VOLUMES}
```

Here, how can I add my docker-compose.yml file to Jenkins DSL i.e **nv_dsl.groovy**, so that I can able to pass parameters from Jenkins DSL that apply to the docker-compose.yml file?

While building a pipeline job, I'm getting the error "The CONTAINER_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added environment variables in Jenkins script whose variables I need to parameterize to YAML file as below and it worked for me as expected,

```
pipeline {
  agent any

 environment {
   CONTAINER_NAME = "${CONTAINER_NAME}"
   PORTS = "${PORTS}"
   VOLUMES = "${VOLUMES}"
   NODE_ENV = "${NODE_ENV}"
   IMAGE = "${IMAGE}"
 }

 parameters {
   choice name: "ENVIRONMENT", choices: environments
 }

 stages {
   stage('Deploy') {
     steps {
       echo "Deploying ${env.REPO} to ${params.ENVIRONMENT}..."
     }
   }
 }
}
```